# c# AWS layers with Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions package

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I'm trying to create a layer for my lambda function developed with Net core 3.1, but I get the following error:

```
zipping: Failed to compress file: open 
dotnetcore\store\x64\netcoreapp3.1\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions\
5.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll:
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

The command that I'm using is:

```
dotnet lambda publish-layer --region us-east-1 --layer-name my-Layers --layer-type runtime-package-store -sb sb-layers -f netcoreapp3.1 --package-manifest package-manifest.xml
```

The package manifest is the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents" Version="2.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson" Version="2.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2" Version="3.7.0.73" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I see that the file path with the error has "netstandard2.0" but I don't know why. Maybe my question is silly, does this mean that I cannot used "microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions" with Net Core 3.1?

Thanks a lot for any information about how to deal with this issue.

Comment: can you show us the  package-manifest.xml file ?

Comment: @Ruben I have updated my post with the package manifest

Comment: @Ruben the problem was related to a long file path. I changed the environment variable TMP to "C:\Temp" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating the package and didnt fail at any point

So, this is what i did.

Updated the dotnet distribution and fresh install aws lambda tools

```
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-5.0
dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools
```

I used the sample DemoLayer as instructed by the AWS tutorials
[AWS tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EF1NES9BX8c)

```
dotnet lambda publish-layer DemoLayer --layer-type runtime-package-store -sb <s3bucket> --package-manifest manifest.xml
```

and above command line uploads all the Package Reference without any error.

Comment: @JaimeCamargo= does this worked for you?

Comment: the problem was related to a long file path. I changed the environment variable TMP to "C:\Temp" and it worked.